# Calling a specific constructor in C# with null

Tags: c#, constructor

I have a class with several constructors and I want to call the "main" one from another - but using null.

Using just `this(null)` results in a compile time error, so I cast null to the type of the other constructor.  Compiles fine.

```
MyClass
{
  public MyClass(SomeType t)
  { }

  public MyClass(IList<FooType> l)
    : this((SomeType)null)
  { }
}
```

This feels, lets just say icky.  Is this okay and common or insane and shows a flaw in the class - in that it should have an empty constructor?

The class "mostly" requires a `SomeType`, but there are rare times when it is okay to not have one.  I want the rare times to "stick out" and be obvious that something "is not a-typical" with the code.

Comment: Redirecting a constructor to another one and leaving the constructor body empty is perfectly fine. But why do you require the `l` parameter if you're not using it?

Comment: I always use `as` when I need to cast `null`, because it reads better and feels less "icky": `null as SomeType`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the cast because `null` by itself is ambiguous. A `null` by itself has no inherent type, so the cast tells the compiler *which* constructor you want to pass `null` to.

That being said, it is probably more meaningful for your class to use a default (no-arg) constructor, like you said. Having all three constructors is probably okay, too.

Comment: I know why I need the cast - but seems strange to cast null to something, so I wanted to get a second opinion on how strange this scenario is.

Comment: It's not uncommon to cast `null` to a specific type. It's one of the joys of overloaded methods.

Answer (score 7):

It does have just a slight smell to it. This technique is used sometimes, but I would avoid it if practically possible.

A parameterless constructor is generally more descriptive than passing null, you can make it private if you only use it from within the class:

```
MyClass {

  private MyClass() {
  }

  public MyClass(SomeType t) {
  }

  public MyClass(IList<FooType> l) : this() {
  }

}
```

Another alternative (but one that doesn't work to call from a constructor) is to put the code in a static method to somewhat isolate it and give it a more descriptive name:

```
MyClass {

  public MyClass(SomeType t) {
  }

  public static MyClass CreateEmptyInstance() {
    return new MyClass((SomeType)null);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my honest opinion this seems like a logic flaw, that will get you into trouble somewhere down the road.  It just seems that at some point a piece of code will be written that will do some validation and break this constructor and you will waste a massive amount of time debugging it.  I do need to further see what it is you are trying to do and why.

Answer (score 0):

I use the "view model first" pattern for MVVM development in WPF/C#, so I'm required to have an empty constructor. Because of that, I invert your pattern and use a nullable as the parameter for design-time. No casting of `null` required as long as it's the only constructor with that number of parameters.

```
public FooClass
{
    public FooClass() : this(null) { }

    public FooClass(Bar? bar)
    {
        _bar = bar ?? new();
        // Whatever else initialization for the class.
    }

    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```